# Absolute integer values comparing and squared values comparing. Is it equivalent?

Tags: c++, performance, comparison

There is the standard way to compare the absolute values of two integers:

```
if (std::abs(a) > std::abs(b))
{
   // code
}
```

Sometimes I meet another way of absolute values comparing based on values squaring:

```
if (a * a > b * b)
{
   // code
}
```

Are these methods equivalent? Is there a difference in the performance of these methods? Which method would you prefer?

Comment: No, they're not equivalent. Either approach has certain edge cases (different in either case), which results in undefined or unspecified behavior.

Comment: I also noticed that the second method can cause overflow. Are there any performance differences?

Comment: It's possible that `a` and `b` hold valid values, that when squared, produce values that are no longer valid (overflow).

Comment: On modern CPUs, it is unlikely that there will be any measurable difference. You do realize that modern CPUs execute millions of operations per second, and are often stalled for I/O activity, which makes any differences in performance completely lost in the noise, right?

Comment: There is significant performance difference. sqrt latency is 4x the multiply latency and sqrt is not fully pipelined. But you can time it on your application.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik  It depends on the problem being solved. There is a wide class of programs where almost all the time is mathematical calculations.

Comment: You'll probably be able to answer your own question first, simply by trying both alternatives, and timing how long each one takes, thus settling the issue. It's unlikely you will find any difference outside of the margin of error.

Comment: @AlainMerigot, `sqrt`  not used in these codes, or am i wrong?

Comment: @DmytroDadyka Yes. I realized that later. fabs and multiply have similar characteristics and should not lead to significant difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until the integer product overflows, the two methods will behave equivalently. I would prefer using `std::abs()` because that more clearly states my intentions- to compare the magnitude of two numbers. If I use the product `a * a`, any other maintainers that read by code will wonder what `a * a` signifies.

While beyond the scope of the literal question, I feel its important to emphasize that these two methods diverge much faster for non-integer types. For floating point, you'll run into rounding errors very quickly, resulting in slightly different comparisons, which may sometimes give the wrong result (one may argue you shouldn't do direct floating point comparisons anyways, and instead clamp to a range, but still).

More subtlety, comparison of `complex` values in this manner will be incorrect. The typical calculation of the absolute value for a complex number `a + bi` is `sqrt(a^2 + b^2)` where `^` denotes exponentiation. However, `(a + bi)^2` will yield `a^2-b^2 + 2abi`, which cannot **ever** be equal for non-zero `a` and `b`.

Comment: The remark that the second method can lead to unexpected results for complex types seems to me important.

Answer (score 1):

Both are only equivalent if the numbers are *small*. For example, if you are using 32 bit int, then a * a will *overflow* around a = 50,000, and a * a > b * b will give completely wrong answers.

Performance is of absolutely no interest. You are in the nanosecond savings territory here. I prefer code that doesn't fail for no serious reasons, so comparing the absolute values is what you should do. It is also apparently what your problem description is.

Comment: I completely agree with you. I work with code in which the second variant is often found. But I think the author is just afraid of stl) I would like to change all these fragments to the first option, but first decided to make sure that I understand correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Absolute value of a number returns its opposite if it's smaller than 0 and itself if it's bigger than 0.

Squaring a number will always give you a positive result, 
so comparing integers squared is the same as comparing their absolute values. Although that might differ with floating numbers.

In short, it's better to use `std::abs` for readability and to avoid having contradictions when working with floats

EDIT:

You can use this Timer class to compare execution time. Just declare an instance of this class at the beginning of the function you want to test.

```
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>
class Timer
{
  private:
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> start;
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> end;

  public:
    Timer()
    {
        start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    }
    ~Timer()
    {
        end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto duration = end - start;
        std::cout << "Function execution took  : " << duration.count() << " ns" << std::endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    Timer t;
    return 0;
}
```